# Is there a javascript framework for native controls that works on both iOS and Android?

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, ios, cross-platform

I'm attempting to make a cross-platform game, for both iOS and Android. It requires both drawing to a canvas (the actual game part) and navigation that would look far nicer via native controls (e.g. selecting options). I would ideally like to write the code once and have it work on both platforms.

This seems quite doable graphics-wise using cocos2d-html5/javascript . I haven't figured it out 100% yet but I gather that I can write all the graphics code in javascript & have it work without modification on iPhone, Android, and html5.

In terms of capabilities like using the filesystem, network, and notifications, it seems that [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/about/feature/) will suit my purposes. I have yet to see how to combine cocos2d-javascript & PhoneGap but it seems theoretically possible.

I see there are javascript libraries that use native controls for the iPhone, for example, [NimbleKit](http://www.nimblekit.com/index.php). That only works on iOS, though. Are there any libraries where the same code will be used to create native-looking controls for both iPhone and Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the game you are writing, performance may or may not be an issue. If it is, using a canvas and a web view might be a problem. As I understand it, you can use the javascript bindings of cocos2d and run it through cocos2d and cocos2d-x on each platform. This will most likely give you better performance, since you get access to OpenGL rendering. Read more about javascript in cocos2d and cocos2d-x here: https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone/wiki/cocos2d-and-JavaScript

When it comes to the UI, cocos2d won't help you access standard components and, as far as I know, neither will Phonegap. If you just want access to some specific feature from the UI, you always have the possibility of writing your own plugin for Phonegap. It is a fairly straightforward process, but probably not something you would like to do for the entire UI. Someone might have already done it though. Phonegap has a ton of plugins.

My advice would be to start by seeing if cocos2d-html5 will give you enough performance. Also, please let me know what you find about the performance. If it works well for mobile devices, cocos2d-html5 seems like a really convenient choice.

Lastly, integration between cocos2d and Phonegap: If you use a cocos2d-html5, integrating should be trivial. Phonegap basically packs a web page in an app, so put your cocos2d-canvas on your page and link to your cocos2d-javascript. Done. If you use the non-html5-version of cocos2d, one way to integrate them would be to put your cocos2d-game in a Phonegap plugin and insert it into your Phonegap page.